# Convert attributed text to HTML

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

In my case I have to convert `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` document to `NSMutableAttributedString` for which I use below snippet

```
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                   options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                             NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                        documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

When I log my `text` I get below for attached screenshot

```
<font color="#ff66b2">dasdasd asd asd asd sa asda&nbsp;</font>
<font color="#00feff">asdasdas &nbsp;asd </font>
<font color="#0000ff">sa asd asdasdsad</font>
```

[image]

Since it's a `UITextView` I need to give edit support also in iPhone. So how can I convert `NSMutableAttributedString` into the formate of string logged?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Partially agreed answer

```
var htmlEncoding: String? {
do {

    let attrubutedString = NSAttributedString(string: self)

    let htmlData = try attrubutedString.data(from:NSMakeRange(0, attrubutedString.length), documentAttributes:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]);

    return String.init(data: htmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

} catch {

    return nil

}

}
```